# div popup relative to field that caused event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Lots of questions about how to center a `div` popup to screen, but I would like my `div` `popup` to be moved to a place next to the field that triggered the JavaScript. How do I reference the position of field in an `onclick` event in the style of my absolute div?

I can pass `'this'` object to my function and change the `left` and `top` of my `absolute/relative` `div`, but what can I do with '`this'` to influence the `div` position?

Would I try something like below?

```
div.style = "top:this.top";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could try

```
 var pos = $(this).position();
 $("div#divid").css('top',pos.top).css('left',pos.left);
```

If you want to use straight javascript you might try

```
var div = document.getElementById("divid");
div.style.top = this.offsetTop;
div.style.left = this.offsetLeft;
```

Whether you want to use .position or .offset for jQuery or offsetTop/Left clientTop/left for javascript depends on whether both elements have the same parent.

a quick demo using jQuery: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdZtz/)

Comment: [Couple](http://jsfiddle.net/KdZtz/2) [variants](http://jsfiddle.net/KdZtz/3) for good measure

Comment: What a wonderful example. But this only works if the buttons are defined as absolute also. In our case, they are not. The buttons are positioned inline.

Comment: The buttons will work if they are position: relative or static as well.  The jQuery .position() function returns the screen location you need.  [yet another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KdZtz/5/)  Buttons 6 and 7 are position relative while 8 is static.   Button 8 doesn't work when it is covered by div#buttons because it never receives the click event, so its handler is not called.